# What would the graph of Density of the medium at $t=T/2$ vs $x$ look like?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, pressure, density

... The displacement equation of a standing wave in a homogeneous elastic medium is given by:

> $y=acos(kx)cos(\omega t)$ where $k$ is the propogation constant( $=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$), a is the amplitude, $\omega$ is the angular frequency.

*What would the graph of Density of the medium at $t=T/2$ vs $x$ look like?*

---

I tried forming the equation but couldn't come to the result required.  Here's what I did:

After looking at the difference of volumes(before the wave has propagated and after the wave has propagated) enclosed by a part of an assumed cylindrical region,
We conclude that:

$\frac{dv}{v}=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Also, $dP=-\beta \frac{dv}{v}$

---

Solving this and using the given equation of standing wave to get $\frac{dy}{dx}$ , we finally obtain:

> $dP=\beta kasin(kx)cos(\omega t)$

Let's assume the air to be an ideal gas. Hence using the ideal gas equation, we get:

> $P=\rho \frac{R\theta}{M}$ where $\rho$ is the density of the medium and $\theta$ is the absolute temperature

Which further gives:

> $d\rho=dP\frac{M}{R\theta}$
> Hence,
> $d\rho=\beta Ka\frac{M}{R\theta}sin(kx)cos(\omega t)$

---

Since we need the graph at $t=\frac{T}{2}$,putting this in the obtained equation we get:

> $d\rho=-\beta Ka\frac{M}{R\theta}sin(kx)$

that is,

> $d\rho=-C.sin(kx)$ where C is any positive constant.

Which should give a simple y=-Csin(x) type of curve. But here's what's given in my book:
[image]